# Как перенести структуру таблиц в другую БД?

Tags: postgresql

Есть локальная и рабочая БД.
После правок на локальной приходится делать её полную копию, удалять рабочую и восстанавливать с нуля.
Это приводит к потере данных.

А как перенести только структуру? 
То есть чтобы обновились таблицы, и если надо то строкам, где есть значение по умолчанию выставлялись эти значения по умолчанию?
Есть ли для этого какие нибудь инструменты?

Comment: Есть - миграции называются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно есть, называется это "миграции"

[Программирование. Web-Разработка. Миграции](http://funny-prog.blogspot.ru/2012/03/php.html)

Comment: Я имею ввиду не через программирование.

Comment: @manking А почему бы вам не записывать все изменения, которые вы делаете на локальной базе в файлик какой-нибудь, а потом эти запросы просто применяете на рабочей базе без потери данных, получатся теже миграции.

Comment: Видимо придется программировать всё таки. Я думал есть "умные" средства дописывающие структуру таблиц, на основе двух бэкапов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте использовать для этого [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). Это open-source java библиотека для отслеживания и применения изменений в схеме БД.
   Вот [здесь](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/01/managing-database-migrations-using-liquibase/) можно посмотреть пример конкретно для Postgresql.
2. Также можно посмотреть на инструмент [Pyrseas](https://github.com/perseas/Pyrseas). Это Python утилита для Postgresql. Он генерирует описание по схеме БД в виде yaml файла. Затем его можно сравнить с любой базой и по разнице автоматически генерируется sql миграция.